# volume home has only 0 bytes disk space remaining unable to start

Tags: boot, 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and facing the error "volume home has only 0 bytes disk space remaining unable to start" on boot.

I ran into this error while I was trying to build a software from source right from my `/tmp` directory. Now I am unable to start my system, and every time I boot it up, it gives me the error message. I am unable to perform any task due to this, and unable to open the terminal window, I tried Ctrl+Alt+Enter, still nothing pops up.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Text terminals should still allow login (eg. ctrl+alt+F4 ; they don't require free space in $HOME which a GUI will require), allowing you to explore where you're disk space has been used up, what files you can remove, or other solution to rectify your problem.  Your error message looks different to the expected messages so I'm unsure where you're seeing it though.

Comment: I opened up a console screen with ctrl+alt+F4